# YII model to handle more than one table

Tags: php, database, activerecord, yii

I am developing a registration form in YII. In my form there is a radio option to choose register as Mode1 or register as Mode2. If user chooses mode1, data's should be entered to table1 or it should entered to table2.
In YII each model deals with one table. Here my form deals with two tables.

So how to handle such a form to validate and enter data's to table in YII?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to create one model for the form (assuming they have the same fields?)
This class would extend **CFormModel** (in the example below I refer to this model as *GlobalFormModel*)

This model would have the same attributes as the other two models, as well as one new attribute called *mode*
When the form is submitted, in the controller you can handle it based on which mode and validate it against the correct model, eg:

```
$model = new GlobalFormModel

if(isset($_POST['GlobalFormModel'])){
    $model->attributes = $_POST['GlobalFormModel']; 

    if ($model->mode == 1){
        $newmodel = new FormOne;
        $newmodel->attributes = $model->attributes;
    } else {
         $newmodel = new FormTwo;
         $newmodel->attributes = $model->attributes;
    } 

    ... // validate and save $newmodel
}

$this->render("yourview",array("model"=>$model));
```

Where FormOne is the model associated with the first table, and FormTwo is associated with the second table. First you create a new instance of the GlobalFormModel (which is passed to the view). You check if the form has been submitted (you could validate it here or after loading one of the two models, that is your choice). You check the mode, and then load the correct model.

Comment: So, I dont want to specify rules in GlobalFormModel(rules specified in the other two model is enough), is not it?

Comment: Well you could add an additional attribute to one of those models, for example FormOne, (his is the model you would pass to the view). When the form is submitted you could then check what that attributes value is and either change the model to FormTwo or keep FormOne. It is the same thing, just less "conventional"